# Refactor switch statement - using an object vs primitive data type

Tags: java, refactoring

I am learning how to refactor Java code with the book [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code (1st edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672). The author does the refactoring shown below and gives an explanation for why he did it which is not clear to me. Can someone help me to understand the explanation? The code is for movie rental software.

```
public class Movie {

    //Lets call these constants "priceCode".
    public static final int  CHILDRENS = 2;
    public static final int  REGULAR = 0;
    public static final int  NEW_RELEASE = 1;

//...more code here...
}

class Rental {
    private Movie _movie;
    private int _daysRented;
//...more code here...
}
```

**BEFORE REFACTORING:**

```
class Rental...
   double getCharge() {
       double result = 0;
       switch (getMovie().getPriceCode()) {
           case Movie.REGULAR:
               result += 2;
               if (getDaysRented() > 2)
                   result += (getDaysRented() - 2) * 1.5;
               break;
           case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
               result += getDaysRented() * 3;
               break;
           case Movie.CHILDRENS:
               result += 1.5;
               if (getDaysRented() > 3)
                   result += (getDaysRented() - 3) * 1.5;
               break;
       }
       return result;
  }
```

We move the above method code into the already existing Movie class.

**AFTER REFACTORING:**

```
 class Movie...
   double getCharge(int daysRented) {
       double result = 0;
       switch (getPriceCode()) {
           case Movie.REGULAR:
               result += 2;
               if (daysRented > 2)
                   result += (daysRented - 2) * 1.5;
               break;
           case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
               result += daysRented * 3;
               break;
           case Movie.CHILDRENS:
               result += 1.5;
               if (daysRented > 3)
                   result += (daysRented - 3) * 1.5;
               break;
       }
       return result;
   }
```

**AUTHOR'S EXPLANATION:**

It is a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object. If you must use a switch statement, it should be on your own data, not on someone else’s.

For this, to work I had to pass in the length of the rental, which of course is data from the rental. The method effectively uses two pieces of data, the length of the rental and the type of the movie. 
Why do I prefer to pass the length of rental to the movie rather than the movie type to the rental? It’s because the proposed changes are all about adding new types. Type information generally tends to be more volatile. If I change the movie type, I want the least ripple effect, so I prefer to calculate the charge within the movie.

**MY QUESTIONS:**

Why is it a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object?

What do these things really mean "type info generally tends to be volatile" and "least ripple effect (is achieved)"? These vague words (volatile and ripple) don't clearly explain the advantage of this refactoring.

**PS** - Please note that this is not the final code. There is more refactoring later in the book. I know that this is an outdated 1990s book. Despite that, it looks like the book has plenty of ideas and concepts about designing code which could still be useful today. But, I am not sure how much help this book will be in 2020. Moreover, the latest version of the book, [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134757599), uses Javascript which I don't know.

Comment: The explanation is as strange as the very idea of a book about *refactoring*. Further, you're reading a book written in 1999, which is teaching a pile of outdated concepts (I wondered whether it's a pre-java5 book before clicking the link... it is). If I were you, I'd send this book to a museum and read something like effective java for starters. This book is even older than [eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software))

Comment: The refactored code improves loose coupling between those classes and encapsulates the implementation of Movie. When new priceCode for Movie arrives, it only needs to be handled in Movie class, not in all classes having a Movie as field. But both before and after code doesn't keep the standards. Commonly would be to make the priceCode a MovieType enum, which could keep the priceCode, multiplication factor or even the whole getCharge(int) inside the enum - this could totally remove the need of switch statement

Comment: I think "type info generally tends to be volatile" in the context of this example means an enum like movie type is more likely to change by business requirement.

So, he prefers to encapsulate it in the movie class. That way when a new movie type is added he only needs to update de Movie class.

Otherwise he should track all references to Movie type in other classes and update it.

There is no absolute way of saying if it is a bad idea or not.

By  "ripple effect" he is probably referring to the situation where a change in a class requires to modify several other classes.

Comment: IMO, "learning how to refactor..." isn't the very best idea, it's better to understand design principles, coding standards and common best practices. Then later when working with some code it comes almost naturally if some piece of code needs to be refactored or not.

Comment: @ernest_k - I knew that this book was outdated before I got it. I chose it despite that because the 2nd edition uses Javascript and I don't know that. Moreover, I thought that I could learn at least some high level concepts or ideas about design. It seems like most of the book could be useful, even though it uses Vectors etc.

Comment: @itwasntme - Yes, but I wanted to see if there is any technique in the book that can still be useful today. At this point I am not sure if the book is even useful in 2020. Could you please suggest any alternatives to this book that teach design principles and best practices instead ?

Comment: There're plenty of them I think, from the top of my head the books from Robert C. Martin, go through wikipedia reading about SOLID, DRY, YAGNI, etc... But as you've read in previous comments this kind of refactoring have it own purposes and advantages. Main reason we've all sugested something newer than this book is because, now the code of your example would look much differently - e.g. the enums. For dynamic movie dypes probably additional service class, etc.

Comment: One thing that hits the eyes is declaring variables with "_" prefix (`Movie _movie`) which probably never was code writing standard in Java. Reasuming, the book might be covering useful topics, but similar to this question the reader must know the concepts behind it and probably in most cases, some piece of code discussed in the book can have simpler implementation using at least Java8.

Comment: @itwasntme - I think the author uses "_" so that he can avoid using "this". _var = var instead of this.var = var might be easier for him.

Comment: Getter/Setter methods are generated/written basing on variable name, so with "_" it would be `get_Movie`? So here you have another reason why not go with this book - using "this" isn't anything bad, doing some crazy naming to avoid "this" is bad. Besides according to your ""this". _var = var instead of this.var = var", why not name the param as "variable", then you could still use "var=variable".

Comment: What the author means is that, its more likely that a new type will be added to the Movie class (volatile). So he wants to keep the methods that operate on the types in the same class. So you won't have to change at a lot of places (ripple effect) when a business decision to add a new type comes along.

Comment: Before going into the question, one should note, as other comments do, that the examples do not adhere to Java naming conventions which are part of the Java Language Specification. See [Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object?

Because if the type of that attribute is changed you have to make changes in your own code.
If type of `Movie.priceCode` is switched from `int` to `enum` then you will also have to change code in `Rental`. But you you move price calculation to `Movie` than you can change type of `Movie.priceCode` without affecting `Rental`.

> What do these things really mean "type info generally tends to be volatile" and "least ripple effect (is achieved)"? These vague words (volatile and ripple) don't clearly explain the advantage of this refactoring.

If you decide to add more price codes to a movie (like HBO series, Disney series, etc) then you will have to make changes in both `Movie` and `Rental` classes. But if you do not use `Movie.priceCode` inside `Rental` then you do not need to change `Rental` class at all even if you remove `priceCode` from movie or rename it or change its type. In this case refactoring help to localize scope of the change. Assume that you write code for `Movie` and another team writes code for `Rental` and you decided to add more price types. Now you need to notify that other team that you added more types, provide them values, logic for calculation, possibly build new artifact with new version of your `Movie` class. But if you only provide them method `getCharge(daysRented)` then you can add whatever new types without notification overhead.

Comment: I think this answer clearly shows what "ripple effect" means; but does not address why "_type info generally tends to be volatile._"

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object?

It isn't.

The author appears to be referring, in general, to what is likely to change in a codebase that is maintained over an extended period, and to the difficulty of making modifications to that codebase.  It's at least conceivable that they could be correct, but this is not any sort of general or generally accepted principle of software development.

Comment: Louis - Some commenters have suggested that I avoid the book because it is from the 1990s. I am not sure if I should because I wonder if the ideas/concepts in the book could still be useful in 2020s (except stuff like Vectors). Some said that it is better to not read books on Refactoring like this one, but instead read books on Design principles, best practices etc. What would you suggest, especially to new engineers at Google ? Thanks.

Comment: _Information Hiding_ is a generally-accepted principle of OOP. Don't you think that's what Fowler is getting at here?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*The answer has been broken into two answers for ease of reading. This is Part-1.*</sub>

---

### Addressing "Author's Explanation":

> It is a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object. If you must use a switch statement, it should be on your own data, not on someone else’s.

I'm surprised at this statement, because `Movie` is a private variable of `Rental` class. Therefore, the switch is not really happening on the attribute of another object. It is happening on the attribute of private object.

Author's refactored code is also in violation of Single Responsibility Principle. `Movie` should be responsible for movie related info only, and not loaded with rental information. Thus, `getCharge()` method seems in its correct place in the `Rental` class.

---

> ... Why do I prefer to pass the length of rental to the movie rather than the movie type to the rental? It’s because the proposed changes are all about adding new types.

Seems incorrect again. In my experience, even in non-movie contexts `Type`s are pretty stable constants. Example: the types of cars are pretty stable - "Car.Sedan", "Car.SUV" etc.

---

> Type information generally tends to be more volatile. If I change the movie type, I want the least ripple effect, so I prefer to calculate the charge within the movie.

To localize the volatility of a type, the specific type should be made an enum, outside of *every* class that uses it. Example: Create the `MovieType` enum outside of both `Movie` and `Rental`. Now every movie will have a private variable that tells what type the current movie is (or what is the priceCode), and the rental object will be able to access that "type" from the getter of its `_movie` private variable.

Whenever you add a type, there are two things that you will have to address:

1. Create the representation of the new type somewhere in your code;
2. Add the business logic that this new type brings with itself.

And you will have to address both of those, irrespective of your implementation. Hence, the ripple is more or less the same. The only thing that will change is the place where you make those changes. When Classes have single responsibility, it is more natural to figure where the changes should be made.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*The answer has been broken into two answers for ease of reading. This is Part-2.*</sub>

---

### Addressing your questions:

> Why is it a bad idea to do a switch based on an attribute of another object ?

Simply because, the other object, is "other" object. You cannot know what is happening inside that object. So the methods would be more stable if they rely on internal variables.

As an example: the `getCharge()` method of `Rental` will return different values if the `getPriceCode()` of `Movie` behaves differently if, let's say, the price code of a movie is changed in between those calls.

However, it is not applicable in this scenario, because `Movie` is stored in the private variable `_movie` of the `Rental` class. The author seems to have overlooked it.

---

> What do these things really mean "type info generally tends to be volatile" and "least ripple effect (is achieved)"? These vague words (volatile and ripple) don't clearly explain the advantage of this refactoring.

The author is trying to highlight that types are added/removed/modified frequently. (My experience has been otherwise though. Types have been stable in the kind of code I have worked on.) And in situation where types are being frequently updated, you want to keep your headache to a minimum by minimizing the repercussions of those updates.

If for every 'type' update you have to modify your code at 20 thousand places, then that's not a good example of "least ripple effect".

But, I think following Single Responsibility Principle here will be far more fruitful than following the author's suggested refactoring. Changes will be the same, but finding the place where those changes have to be made will be more intuitive for current and future developers.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using `switch-case` statement in Java leads to the pour readability of the code. Since Java is preferred as an Object Oriented Language, it is much appreciated in writing everything in an `explicit` way.

Using `switch` statement in Java along with keyword `break` would lead to the programming as `procedure` way instead. In general, we could say it is hard to understanding what the `break` means.

Therefore, to refactor the `switch` statement by replacing with `If-else` statement will improve the `clean code`.

I only use `switch-case` in Java even if on `enum` case, as much recommended in the `Effective Java` book (3rd Edition, page 167).